# Ansible mapping value issue when usnig echo module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am learning ansible and i am suing shell command to add parameter in LDAP config file.

```
echo -e "dn: cn=default, ou=policy, dc=com, dc=com \n changetype: modify \n replace: pwdMaxAge \n pwdMaxAge: 0\n" > /tmp/age.txt
```

But ansible throws the error saying that

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed here

 shell:  echo -e "dn:    cn=default,
                    ^
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to single quote wrap it,

```
shell: 'echo -e "dn: cn=default, ou=policy, dc=com, dc=com \n changetype: modify \n replace: pwdMaxAge \n pwdMaxAge: 0\n" > /tmp/age.txt'
```

Also, since you are learning, you might want to deploy a [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html) or [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) a file instead of using shell and text redirect.